# async MVVM command returning immediately

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mvvm, async-await

Following some excellent help in [a similar question I asked recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37379755/706346), and a similar example shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13310521/706346), I tried to apply this to a command in an MVVM view model as follows...

```
private async void BookAppointmentCommandExecute() {
  Debug.WriteLine("VM Start");
  IsBusy = true;
  await Task.Run(() => Service.BookAppointment(Appointment.ID, PatientID));
  IsBusy = false;
  Debug.WriteLine("VM Done");
}
```

The WCF service call looks like this...

```
[OperationContract]
public void BookAppointment(int appointmentID, int patientID) {
  Debug.WriteLine("Svc Start");
  Task.Delay(1000);
  AppointmentsServiceLogic.BookAppointment(appointmentID, patientID);
  Debug.WriteLine("Svc Done");
}
```

The `Task.Delay` was added to simulate network latency, so I can check if the busy indicator on the view is displayed correctly. It wasn't.

In both cases, the `Debug.WriteLine` statements were added to help me see what was going on.

Unlike the two samples I linked, my code doesn't suspend execution at the `await` line in the command method, but instead carries on immediately. From the results in the Output window, I can see the delay caused by the `Task.Delay` happens **after** the command method has finished executing...

```
40:30:409 VM Start
40:30:409 Svc Start
40:30:409 VM Done
40:31:410 Svc Done
```

As you can see, the command method completed immediately, then there was a one second delay (after IsBusy had been set back to false), and only then did the service method return. I thought the idea was that the command method's execution was suspended until the `awaited`ed method had completed.

Anyone able to explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use Thread.Sleep instead of Task.Delay

Comment: Anyone able to explain why this was put on hold? Looking at the reason given, it seems I didn't include the desired behaviour. Hmm, I said `...so I can check if the busy indicator on the view is displayed correctly. It wasn't` which seems like a pretty clear description of the problem to me. Also, I included the only two methods relevant, so the problem is reproducible from the code given. What was off-topic about it? I'm not trying to start an argument, I want to know how to improve my questions.

Comment: It seems to me that the close reason banner is pretty clear: you have failed to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem. This makes your question off-topic, no matter how good someone might be at _guessing_ what the problem is.

Comment: @PeterDuniho What more code should I have provided? I said that the first method was an MVVM view model command method, so any extra code would have been worthless, as anyone familiar with MVVM would know immediately where this went. The second method was a WCF service call. Again, anyone with even a minimal knowledge of WCF would know that this lives inside a WCF service. What more code should I have provided? I'm not being awkward, I really want to know what more I could have done. I thought carefully before posting, and provided all of the code that I thought was needed to see the problem.

Comment: _"What more code should I have provided"_ -- [mcve]. What part of that document are you having trouble understanding? Asking over and over "what more I could have done?" when that information has been provided to you multiple times doesn't seem reasonable to me. If you are having trouble comprehending the guidance given you, please be more specific. Don't just keep repeating the same question over and over; acknowledge the guidance given you and state what _specific_ part of that guidance you don't understand.

Comment: And just to be clear: had you provided a good [mcve], your question would a) not have been closed (or at least, not for that reason...there's a good chance it's a duplicate as well, but that's a whole separate issue), and b) had it not been closed for some other reason, you'd have your answer by now, because **with a good [mcve], it's trivial for anyone else to reproduce your problem and fix it**. You got one person willing to take a stab at it, but you said his answer didn't work, and it didn't work because you didn't provide enough detail in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a misunderstanding on how `async-await` works. Check out the blog of Stephen Cleary for an introduction: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Some quick sample code to illustrate your problem:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Start");
await MyAsyncTask();
Debug.WriteLine("End");
```

The `await` keyword executes the Task following it (so the method `MyAsyncTask`) to execute asynchronous, but waits for it to finish before continuing execution (which means "End" is printed to the console after `MyAsyncTask` finished exceution)

Another example:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Start");
MyAsyncTask();
Debug.WriteLine("End");
```

Now "End" is written to the console immediately after `MyAsyncTask` was started, so before its completion.

Applied to your specific example I'd say a way to do this would be

```
private async void BookAppointmentCommandExecute() {
    Debug.WriteLine("VM Start");
    IsBusy = true;
    await Service.BookAppointment(Appointment.ID, PatientID); //as I've changed the return type of the method below, I can now directly await it
    IsBusy = false;
    Debug.WriteLine("VM Done");
}

//the method should return Task, so you can use the await keyword to wait for its completion
//I've marked the method with the async keyword so I can use the await keyword within
[OperationContract]
public async Task BookAppointment(int appointmentID, int patientID) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Svc Start");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    //(depending if AppointmentsServiceLogic.BookAppointment is implemented asynchronous)
    await AppointmentsServiceLogic.BookAppointment(appointmentID, patientID);
    //or
    await Task.Run(() => AppointmentsServiceLogic.BookAppointment(appointmentID, patientID));
    Debug.WriteLine("Svc Done");
}
```

Comment: I freely admit to not understanding it! I've read and re-read that blog, and am still having trouble getting my head around it, which is why I asked here. Anyway, I tried your suggestion, but it didn't help. I made the service call async as you suggested, and updated the service reference in the client app, but the VM method still ended before the service method returned. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you use the debugger on both sides, to see what's going on? Also, are you sure you are `await`ing the wcf call?